# Ranking gases by value of the van der Waals equation-of-state constant 'a'?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws

How can I find out which gas has the highest value of the van der Waals constant $a$?

Example set of gases in ascending order of $a$: $\ce{NO2}$, $\ce{CO2}$, $\ce{H2}$, $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{CCl4}$.

Comment: Taken from your comment to Max' answer, I think what you are really asking is how you can determine the value of a for any gas without looking it up. I think that would be a valid question. However, now your question was treated as if it was a homework question, because as it is posed, you simply have to look up the values. Hence it is not a good fit for our format. I recommend [edit]ing your question, so that it can be reopened and properly answered.

Answer (score 1):

You look up the values of "a" in a [table of constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_constants_%28data_page%29) for the van der Waals equation.

\begin{array}{lrr}
   \text{gas}                  &
    a / \mathrm{L^2bar\,mol^{-2}} &
    b / \mathrm{L\,mol^{-1}}      \\\hline
   \text{Hydrogen}             &    0.2476  &         0.02661 \\
   \text{Carbon dioxide}       &    3.640  &         0.04267 \\
   \text{Nitrogen dioxide}     &    5.354   &         0.04424 \\
   \text{Water}             &    5.536  &         0.03049 \\
   \text{Carbon tetrachloride} &  19.7483  &         0.1281  \\
\end{array}

Comment: Yes, but if I do not have this table which criterion should ultilizar to determine which has the greatest 'a'? type polarity?

Comment: So I find some function of the critical temperature that gives the constant "a." How do you get the critical temperature? You look it up in a table. What is the difference?!? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation#Reduced_form